# Background Notification shows only once

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I use the Android NotificationCompat.Builder and each time the a user opens the app or closes it it sends a background notification.

I want to know what should I write to make so that this notification will show up only once in generally. It means that if a user once got this notification or delted it from his screen it won't show this notification again?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context, channelID)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon))
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
                .setContentTitle("")                                                          .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.message))
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000})
                .setSound(null)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            startForeground(id, notification);
            stopForeground( false );
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
```

Comment: You must have to put something that you had done. How helpers will get to know that what you have done wrong?

Comment: sorry i added it now

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag using SharedPreferences to check if you have already sent the notification. If you have sent you can update the flag to 1. The next time if you get the flag value as 1, skip sending the notification.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("app", 0);
int notificationFlag = preferences.getInt("notification", 0);

if (notificationFlag == 0) {
     // The notification is not yet sent.
     // Send the notification first and mark the flag as 1
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putInt("notification", 1)
} else {
     // The Notification is already sent once.
}
```